# Silverlight - Close Browser Window

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that launches another Silverlight application in a new browser window. The new Silverlight application has a button called "Close". When a user clicks "Close", I run the following code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("close");
```

This code works on IE just fine. However, it does not work in Chrome. How do I write code that will close the window in both IE and Chrome?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known issue in Chrome browser. To workaround it, insert the following line before you call "close":

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("open", new object[] {"", "_self", ""} );
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("close");
```

Comment: 1+ for handy tip: Horrible that we have to do things like that :)

Comment: This closes the window that opened my dialog window. How do I close the dialog window itself from the dialog window?